# django many to many field does not save

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have the following models:

```
class Offering(models.Model):  
    entity = models.OneToOneField('companies.entity')
    company_type = models.ManyToManyField(CompanyTypeChoice, blank=True)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Tag(models.Model):  
    word = models.CharField(max_length=64)

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Entity(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='companies', blank=True, null=True)

class CompanyTypeChoice(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I have the following loop that I want to create a M2M tag relation:

```
offerings = Offering.objects.all()
    for o in offerings:
        for ct in o.company_type.all():
            tag = Tag.objects.get(word=ct.title)
            e = Entity.objects.get(pk=o.entity.id)
            e.tags.add(tag)
```

This does not save the M2M relationship. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is Django set to autocommit? Also is `CompanyTypeChoice` model fine?

Comment: @BishwasMishra . I haven't changed the default on autocommit.  CompanyType has values and is feeding the loop.  I have posted the CompanyTypeChoice model as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this loop ran once and entered all of the values in.  The duplicates didn't run again and did not throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified related_name = "companies" for tags in your Entity model. So, thats why your many to many value not getting saved. To solve this, replace your line,

```
e.tags.add(tag)
```

with,

```
e.companies.add(tag)
```

I hope this helps.